# Java Webclient: How to serialize to Pascal JSON?

Tags: java, json, webclient, pascal

I am trying to interface with another system that is has extremely specific integration parameters. They don't have any code written to ignore case sensitivity and, long story short, for a post request I am trying to make, they are expecting a JSON body with field names in Pascal case instead of Camel Case and the request fails without Pascal. We are using WebClient to send integration calls so we can support reactive flows in our code. As far as I've been able to tell, when I use WebClient to serialize to JSON, the request is being converted to use Camel Case, which I would normally want.

How can I serialize this to Pascal instead? Everything I try to research about this ends up landing me in .NET land, but I'm not writing this in C#. I'm writing it in Java.

```
//For example:
{"originTypeCode":"US","camelCaseFieldName":"FAILED"}     // FAILURE
{"OriginTypeCode":"US","PascalFieldName":"SUCCESS"}       // SUCCESS
```

I have two ideas:

1) This seems less ideal, but perhaps more intuitive. The idea is to convert the object I'm trying to post to JSON first, then with a parser convert all the fields from Camel Case to Pascal, then try and post that with my WebClient method. This doesn't seem like the most ideal way to do this. I'd imagine there is probably something a lot cleaner.

2) The second idea is that my WebClient instance serializes using a Jackson serializer. I think if I were to create a new Bean of WebClient/Jackson ObjectMapper, maybe I can write a custom converter to use specifically for this integration flow. This seems like it is perhaps cleaner, but digging through WebClient and it's build methods, it's difficult to figure out how to accomplish this. Below I'm posting the beans as I have them currently defined. Digging into this kind of thing is pretty new to me, so I'm not sure what would need to be changed or where. The WebClient bean is from a WebClientConfig class and the ObjectMapper is from my JacksonConfig class.

```
@Bean
public WebClient webClient() {
    return WebClient.builder().clientConnector(getClientHttpConnector()).build();
}

@Bean
@Primary
public ObjectMapper objectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = builder.createXmlMapper(false).build();
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    return objectMapper;
}
```

I am definitely open to other suggestions as well.

Comment: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.UpperCamelCaseStrategy.html and https://java-focus.com/jackson-property-naming-strategy/

Comment: These were tremendously helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments from @GriffeyDog have helped me figure out what I need to do. For anyone that stumbles across this, the solution was the following:

If you want certain classes to serialize in specific ways, you can annotate the class itself with the annotation @JsonNaming, and then specify a naming strategy, a list of which can be found here: https://java-focus.com/jackson-property-naming-strategy/. For my use case, I used PropertyNamingStrategy.UpperCamelCaseStrategy.

```
@JsonNaming(value = PropertyNamingStrategy.UpperCamelCaseStrategy.class)
public class MyPascalSerializedClass {}
//All fields in this class will serialize to "UpperCamelCase" instead of "normalCamelCase".
```

Additionally, if you wanted to specify certain fields, you can use the @JsonProperty annotation to override even the class annotation. For example, I had a field within my class that had to map to a JSON format that didn't fit to any standard convention, so I was able to use this.

```
@JsonProperty("ULDNumber")
private String uldNumber
//This field will serialize to the specified "ULDNumber".
```

This is all part of the com.fasterxml.jackson library. For further documentation you can refer to the link above and the following: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.UpperCamelCaseStrategy.html